# Inversion of a dependent clause

Tags: inversion, subordinate-clauses

Can one at all say, in trying to bring some color to the style: "it is shown in an, unconnected with previous studies, work, that …", in the stead of the usual: "it is shown in a work, unconnected with previous studies, that …", or that's simply incorrect English?

Answer (score 1):

It's not really *ambiguous* (since the meaning can always be worked out) or strictly *incorrect*, but stylistically the only reason to use this construction is to emphasize an awkward or almost stuttering voice, as though someone were trying to figure out what they wanted to say after they'd mostly said it already. In all other cases, it should be avoided entirely.

Comment: Exactly. It's so unnecessarily awkward that it seems intentionally obtuse.